# Is there a rule for prime numbers?

Tags: math, primes

I've passed by this article:
http://gauravtiwari.org/2011/12/11/claim-for-a-prime-number-formula/

and this paper:
http://www.m-hikari.com/ams/ams-2012/ams-73-76-2012/kaddouraAMS73-76-2012.pdf

They say that there is a formula that when I give it (n) then it returns nth prime number. Where in other articles they say that no formula discovered so far that does such thing.

If the formula exists indeed, then why from time to time they discover the largest prime number known ever, It would be very simple using the formula to find a larger one.

I just want to ensure that such formula exists or not.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I think that this is probably a better fit for math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: There is no "rule" but there are various tricks and search strategies, especially for primes that have a particular form. Anyway, there's a lot more to it than that: it's an entire branch of number theory. You should try your question on http://math.stackexchange.com/ though, not here.

Comment: I've made am algorithm that derived the primes up to 1 million in a matter of a couple of seconds.  This appears to be an algorithm which not a real mathematical formula as it involves case statements and multiple uses of the "floor" operation.  Btw, you would probably get much better answers in math.stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. And sorry for asking in the wrong place. I'll ask the same question there in math.stackexchange.com as you suggested :)

Comment: Those formulas won't help you much for computing primes, because you have to do a lot of work for computing the sums in them.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually it is very simple to test that a given number `n` is a prime number: just check for all smaller numbers 'm' (larger than 1) whether 'm' divides 'n' without remainder. If 
such an 'm' exists 'n' is not a prime number.

Then, to find the `k`-th prime number you just iterate this procedure until you found the `k`-th number which is a prime. So yes, such a formula exists.

But, executing the above procedure is **very** inefficient. So even having this formula (and in real cases you would use more intelligent variants), it can take literally ages before you get an answer. And that is why more efficient variants and tricks are used to find large prime numbers.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a formula for the k-th prime number, it more of an algorithmic use of [primal testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test).